# This statement gives an error saying "Expression must be a modifiable lvalue"

Tags: arrays, c, conditional-operator, lvalue

I have declared a two dimensional character array matrix[][].

```
char matrix[3][3] = {{' ', ' ', ' '},{' ', ' ', ' '},{' ', ' ', ' '}};
```

In a function vacantCenter(), I am trying to return 1, if matrix[1][1] stores a whitespace, else 0 if it doesn't.

```
int vacantCenter()
{
   int n;
   (matrix[1][1] == ' ')? n = 1: n = 0;
   return n;
}
```

A simple if case works fine. But the ternary operator shows an error saying "expression must be a modifiable lvalue". What's wrong in these lines? (I am using Visual Studio 2022; In a .c source file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) of the assigment operator `=` is lower than ther ternary operator `?:`.

Therefore, your expression is interpreted as:

```c
((matrix[1][1] == ' ')? n = 1: n) = 0;
```

Add parenthesis to make it work:

```c
(matrix[1][1] == ' ')? n = 1: (n = 0);
```

Better thing is not to write such a tricky code. Your function `vacantCenter` can be written as:

```c
int vacantCenter()
{
   return matrix[1][1] == ' ';
}
```

or (if you are not confident with how the `==` operator is evaluated):

```c
int vacantCenter()
{
   return matrix[1][1] == ' ' ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, C++ seems to have fixed this.

Comment: I know how the == operator works. I feel dumb that I did not think of using "  return matrix[1][1] == ' ';  ". I was just trying something different. But I found that, there is not much point in using that function.  Thanks for showing me how the precedence works in ternary operator, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears `matrix` is a global variable, you could just use something like:

```
#define VACANTCNTR (matrix[1][1] == ' ')
```

Then:

```
if( VACANTCNTR ) {
    ....
}
```